# wordpress childs custom post linked to parent custom post

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination, custom-post-type

i need to have this hierarchy in wordpress :

i have a custom post type, each post can be linked with another custom post type on this way :

exemple :

```
Custom post 1 - Post example 1 

--- Custom post 2 > 1 

--- Custom post 2 > 2 

--- Custom post 2 > 3
```

When i add a new custon post 2 it should display on the post: Custom post 1 > Post example 1

If it's not clear enough we can take the example of series with seasons :

```
- Serie name saison 1

--- episode 1 

--- episode 2 

--- episode 3
```

I know there is a way to do that in wordpress because i saw it somewhere, the url was :

```
site.com/post1/1/ 
site.com/post1/2/
site.com/post1/3/
```

Someone can help me with this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could read up on and install a couple of plugins or write something yourself. I use a combination of Breadcrumb NavXT and WP Page Navi:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ for pagination.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/ for breadcrumbs (Home > page > location)

If you are talking about the URL structure, you'd need to look at setting up your permalinks. You could take a look at this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

For relationship building, you could take a look at posts 2 posts: 
http://pippinsplugins.com/introduction-posts-2-posts-plugin/

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not what i'm trying to do, i'm trying to do relationships betwen posts

Comment: Great - maybe add that to your question.

Comment: How about posts 2 posts: http://pippinsplugins.com/introduction-posts-2-posts-plugin/